# Best way to run VIM on OS X?

Tags: macos, vim

What is the best way to run VIM in OS X? Should I open the terminal and type vim or use the macvim package?

I like the terminal version, but I can't run it by simply clicking an icon in the dock. I always need to go to Go->Utilities->Terminal.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I've already answered a very similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5894021/546861)

The short version: I use GUI Vim and CLI Vim exactly the same way with the same config. For all intent and purpose, I consider them to be the same editor so using one or the other is just a matter of context.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can approach this.

- You can use **Spotlight** and type 'term' and it should just show up
- Once you have term show up in your dock, right click on term -> 'options' -> 'Keep in dock'

As for the best way to run Vim, I'd say that *it depends on your usage*. Macvim is great, but if you are in/out of a terminal session a lot, then might want to use the one in term.

Also, if you are looking for a good editor, [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) has a [vintage mode](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html) which allows for Vim commands to be run with a traditional editor.

Answer (score 0):

I use MacVim. You could use Quicksilver to enable quick access to apps like Terminal. I imagine, you could also set up an Automator workflow to launch a script that would launch terminal and vim for your via a shortcut.