# How to setup the Mac terminal for Programming with Python?

Tags: python, ide, development-environment

I would like to know from you guys how you have set up your Mac terminal for python programming. I havent done anything big so far (have used ide's until now) with python in terminal but I think that you can do all kinds of fancy things (automatic fill up functions, colors, ...). Any suggestions??

Thanks you guys!

Comment: That will be mostly through `vim` or `nano`

Comment: for syntax highlighting the command will be `:syntax on`

Comment: I have heard about macvim. Would you recommend that one?

Comment: Yes I have used it. It's nice and simpler for someone to use who hasn't used `vim`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892547/what-are-the-advantages-of-macvim-over-vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Python is already on your computer:

Go to /Applications folder

Then open Utilities

Double Click Terminal to open it and get a command line

type 'python' in the command prompt

Your all set!