# Installing Vim with homebrew

Tags: vim, homebrew

After installing vim with homebrew how how do you configure the .vimrc and .gvimrc paths.

Comment: no space after `apt`! FYI, `apt` stands for `Annotation Processing Tool` provided by JDK, which, as the message says, may be deprecated/retired.

Comment: The command you are looking for is `apt-get` without a space before the dash. This is a site for programming questions, though.

Comment: the command is just: `apt-get install git-core`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? vim installed via homebrew reads `~/.vimrc` by default. if you're trying to use a `vimrc` from elsewhere, it's usually easier to symlink it to `~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

After installing vim with homebrew you should install macvim

```
brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim
```

override is to connect to mvim by enter vim at command line.

In the stuation vim needs to be installed as well.

```
# mercurial required - install if you don't already have it.
 brew install mercurial

# install Vim
 brew install vim

# if /usr/bin is before /usr/local/bin in your $PATH,
# hide the system Vim so the new version is found first
 sudo mv /usr/bin/vim /usr/bin/vim72

# should return /usr/local/bin/vim
 which vim
```

once all installs are done you can run vim from command line by typing vim.
once vim is open press

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>

type

```
version
```

Press the down key till you see

```
system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
```

from here you see that your .vimrc file and .gvimrc file exist and you know how to get to them. navigate to them and edit to your desire.

At this point vim is working and you may install plugins.

if these paths do not exist you may create them by navigating to where they belong via command prompt and entering

```
vim .vimrc
```

and

```
vim .gvimrc
```

The easiest way to install plugins at this point... In my opinion is to use vundle. 
follow this tutorial to install vundle.

http://c7.se/switching-to-vundle/

Comment: Why do you need macvim when you have vim already?

Comment: This is why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892547/what-are-the-advantages-of-macvim-over-vim

Comment: I always use method this to setup a new machine with vim and macvim +1 for homebrew!

Comment: Warning: macvim: --override-system-vim was deprecated; using --with-override-system-vim instead